# Extract units from string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string like this:

```
str1='x[cm],z,y[km]'
```

I want to find the units available in the above variable.
If I use `re.findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_/*^\\(\\)-\.]+)\]", str1)`
then it gives `['cm', 'km']`, but I want the output to be `['cm', '', 'km']` since `z` has no unit associated. How can I achieve this?

Similaly for input string `T(x[g],y,z[m])[kg]` the output should be `['g','','m','kg']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
((?<!\])|(?<=\[)[^\[\],]*)\]?(?:,|\)|$)
```

Explanation:

```
(             # open capturing group
  (?<!\])     #   the match is not preceded by a closed squared bracket
              #   match an empty string
|             # OR
  (?<=\[)     #   the match is preceded by an open squared bracket 
  [^\[\],]*   #   match zero or more characters that are neither squared brackets nor commas
)             # close capturing group
\]?           # consume an optional closed squared bracket
(?:,|\)|$)    # consume a comma or a closed parenthesis or match the end of the string
```

`re.findall` will output the content of the capturing group.

Comment: the above regex is giving `['g', '', 'kg']` for `'T(x[g],y,z[m])[kg]'`, its not including `'m'`

Comment: I edited it before your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and the problem gets easier.
To extract the unit from each substring you can write:

```
def extract_unit(s: str) -> str:
    match = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]", s)
    return s[match.start() + 1: match.end() - 1] if match else ""
```

and to create the list you can add the following code:

```
l = [extract_unit(s) for s in str1.split(',')]
```

Comment: Wouldn't work with `T(x[g],y,z[m])[kg]`

Comment: Oh true! It works though by replacing the `')'` brackets with a `','`. `str1 = str1.replace(')', ',')`

Answer (score 0):

This fix is certainly not regex-expert. Still, reformat your input to add empty brackets to relevant fields. Then you can use a simple regex to catch what you want.

```
import re

str1 = 'T(x[g],y,z[m])[kg]'

str1 = ''.join([x if '[' in x else x + '[ ]' for x in str1.split(',')])

print(re.findall(r'\[([\w\s]+)\]', str1))
```

Output:

```
['g', ' ', 'm', 'kg']
```